# How to search specific email in hundreds of email recipient mailbox

Tags: javascript, java, outlook, imap, testcomplete

I have an automation task to validate emails sent to the customer as well as broker and sub-broker, how can I validate each email on the recipient side in the test environment.

Comment: You can't. As a general rule, people don't like to be tracked. Email standards are designed to accommodate that.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit lacking in detail.

If the brokers and subbrokers are real:

You use imap and java, so I assume you use javamail, which includes [a suitable mechanism](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/mail/src/main/java/com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/IMAPProtocol.java#L655), which your server may or may not support. A username can be specially designated as being permitted to log in to other usernames. So subbroker@example.com can read subbroker's own mail with the normal password, but specialprivilegedusername@example.com can also read subbroker's mail, and [authplain()](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/mail/src/main/java/com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/IMAPProtocol.java#L655) is the way to use that feature.

If supported by the server. Quite often it's not.

If the brokers and subbrokers are in the test environment: Why not just set everyone's password to 1234? Then javamail can access everything, no problem.